# how to write an effective and correct while loop

Tags: c++

I'm studying Data Structure and I encounter the Inorder Traversal in Threaded Tree (A special kind of Binary Search Tree).

The idea is to print out the element in a Binary Search Tree in order(smaller to greater) and do not use stack or recursion.

Here's the textbook's code - which is amazingly short and elegant:

```
template<class T>
void ThreadedTree<T>::inorder() {
    ThreadedNode<T> *prev, *p = root;
    if (p != 0) {                   // process only nonempty trees;
        while (p->left != 0)        // go to the leftmost node;
            p = p->left;
        while (p != 0) {
            visit(p);               // "visit" is a function. Its role is to print out the element p points to
            prev = p;
            p = p->right;           // go to the right node and only
            if (p != 0 && prev->successor == 0) // if it is a
                while (p->left != 0)// descendant go to the
                    p = p->left;    // leftmost node, otherwise
        }                           // visit the successor;
    }
}
```

I want to ask how can we write similar while loop of our own? Is there any tricks to think while loop? (Like thinking recursively). I follow the code by hand and the author seems to anticipate everything.

Thank you

Comment: Write a lot of code, pay attention to your code crafting skills, be always on the look out for improving your skill -- from your own code as well as others' code.

Comment: Your question is more about how he has structured and considered all possible test cases. Steps to follow- identify possible scenarios, identify edge cases and design your code to handle all cases.

Comment: Remember that you're reading the finished code in a book. The book doesn't tell you how long the author worked on getting that both correct and concise.

Comment: This is a reasonably reliable procedure: 1) Solve the problem far away from a compiler; 2) Write down your solution as comments; 3) Translate the comments to code.